# Facebook Share Error when moved from one page to another. MVC

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I had this working yesterday on a page, the requirement has now changed and they would like this share functionality to be on the thank you page, so I have moved the code over to that new page, this is the meta part of the page.  The title and image get set dynamically via the model passed in, which I don't believe is causing the issue

```
@section metas{
  <meta property="og:title" content="@Model.YoghurtTitle" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Check out the flavour I have just created!" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/Content/FlavourLab/Combinations/@Model.ImageCombination" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/thank-you" />
}
```

This is my current set up of the share button

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row col-lg-12 text-center danoneBlue">
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/thank-you" data-layout="button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the script

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
@section scripts{
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
}
```

and when I right click view source on the page this is what I see in the head section

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="Check out the flavour I just made! Cool Yoghurt" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="Check out the flavour I have just created!" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/Content/FlavourLab/Combinations/danone_ultimate_coconut_vanilla.png" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/thank-you" />
```

Everything looks correct.  Yet when I run the facebook [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) on the following URL http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/thank-you

I get errors which are as follows:

1. Object at URL 'http://danone.staging-eurorscg.com.au/flavour-lab' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

I have no idea where its getting flavour lab from, yes the script was on that page before but its now been moved and updated via [Facebook Developer Plugin Share](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) and now lives on the thank you page.

Comment: This is what Facebook sees when they scrape your page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdanone.staging-eurorscg.com.au%2Fthank-you

Comment: @WizKid Correct that's the old page (Flavour-lab) where the script use to live, its now been moved to the thank-you page